# Replace groups of characters by newline

Tags: unix, sed, text-processing

I have a line with `', '` in my file, and I want to replace this with an `new line`

***Input:***

```
['siteed01pg|10.229.16.153|10.229.0.0|19|test / crt|BACKUP_MUT_SD  Vlan981 (PVLAN 1981)  New Backup Subnet #1  (site SD)', 'siteed01pg|10.129.135.53|10.129.135.0|26|test / crt|Fmer  bopreprodback  Vlan 754', '
[...]
```

***My sed command:***

```
sed "s/\', \'/\n/g"
```

***Output:***

```
['siteed01pg|10.229.16.153|10.229.0.0|19|test / crt|BACKUP_MUT_SD  Vlan981 (PVLAN 1981)  New Backup Subnet #1  (site SD)nsiteed01pg|10.129.135.53|10.129.135.0|26|test / crt|Fmer  bopreprodback  Vlan 754n
```

in my output the line break has been replaced by the character `n`
Why ?

Comment: if perl is okay, you can use `perl -pe "s/', '/\n/g"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` like this to use `\n` in replacement:

```
sed "s/', '/"$'\\\n'"/g" file
```

Here we are using `$'\n'` to use a newline character in replacement. We ended up using ``$'\\n'`due to use of double quotes around`sed` command.

As per `man bash`:

> Words  of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard

or else with multiline `sed`:

```
sed "s/', '/\\
/g" file
```

This will work on both gnu and POSIX sed versions on bash.

PS: If you're using `gnu sed` then a simplified command would be:

```
sed "s/', '/\n/g" file
```

```
['siteed01pg|10.229.16.153|10.229.0.0|19|test / crt|BACKUP_MUT_SD  Vlan981 (PVLAN 1981)  New Backup Subnet #1  (site SD)
siteed01pg|10.129.135.53|10.129.135.0|26|test / crt|Fmer  bopreprodback  Vlan 754

[...]
```

Comment: can you explain why `$`

Comment: I have added an explanation in answer.